# log4j.properties FileAppender filename pattern

Tags: log4j, configuration-files

I have been using slf4j/logback for a while and our customized file name in the logback.xml is:

```
<timestamp key="ymd" datePattern="yyyyMMdd" />
<timestamp key="hms" datePattern="HHmmss" />
... ...
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/var/log/${ymd}/${HOSTNAME}-${USER}-${hms}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/var/log/${ymd}/${HOSTNAME}-${USER}-${hms}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

Now I switch to slf4j/log4j. How to have the similar log file name pattern in log4j.properties?

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/var/log/${ymd}/${HOSTNAME}-${USER}-${hms}.log?
```

Answer (score 2):

With [Log4J 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/), an equivalent configuration (log4j2.properties) would be:

```
name = MyApp

property.ymd=$${date:yyyyMMdd}
property.hms=$${date:HHmmss}

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName =/var/log/${ymd}/${env:HOSTNAME}-${env:USER}-${hms}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern =/var/log/${ymd}/${env:HOSTNAME}-${env:USER}-${hms}.%i.log

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1KB

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile
```

You did not specify the triggering policy for logback, so I've used a simple SizeBasedTriggerPolicy for the demo purposes.

With **Log4J 1** is it not possible (at least to my best knowledge) to achieve the same by pure configuration means, so you will have to resort to the programmatic configuration, e.g.:

```
//Parameters
String user = System.getenv("USER2");
String host = System.getenv("HOSTNAME");

Date now = new Date();
String day = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(now);
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(now);

//Filename pattern
String pattern = String.format("/var/log/%s/%s-%s-%s",day,host,user,time);

//Create a new RollingFileAppender instance
RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender();
appender.setName("ROLLING");
appender.setFile(pattern+".log");

FixedWindowRollingPolicy policy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
    policy.setFileNamePattern(pattern+".%i.log");
    policy.setMinIndex(1);
    policy.setMaxIndex(5);
    policy.activateOptions();
appender.setRollingPolicy(policy);

appender.setTriggeringPolicy(
    new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(1000)
);

appender.setLayout(
    new PatternLayout("%d %m%n")
);

appender.activateOptions();

//Attach it to the ROOT logger
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(
    appender
);
```

Please note that [Log4J 1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) has officially reached the "end of life" back in 2015:

> On August 5, 2015 the Logging Services Project Management Committee announced that Log4j 1.x had reached end of life. For complete text of the announcement please see the Apache Blog. Users of Log4j 1 are recommended to upgrade to Apache Log4j 2

So it is highly recommended to upgrade to 2.X, unless it is not an option for some reason.

Comment: But what's with Log4J 1?

Comment: AFAIK this can not be done in Log4J 1, by pure configuration means.
There is a RollingFileAppender and a FixedWindowRollingPolicy (log4j-extras), which can be used to roll the files based on index, and there is a DailyRollingAppender/TimeBasedRollingPolicy, which can be used to include the date in the filename, but to my best knowledge it is not possible to do both at once.

Comment: This is pretty easy to overcome by writing some code (set the system properties for "ymd"/"hms" timestamps or implement a custom appender/rollingpolicy),
but IMO that makes little sense to do, as Log4J 1 has been long [deprecated](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces), so upgrading to 2.0, instead, is a far better option.